# How to fix this issue using sequelize and electron with vite?

Tags: electron, sequelize.js, vuejs3, vite, electron-vue

I have created a fresh electron-vite on vue-ts setup from this source https://electron-vite.org/ and installed sequelize. now i am having an error attached here:

[error on npm run dev from the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaGLA.png)

Here's my current code from `main.ts`

[main ts file adding sequelize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iGmP.png)

Here's the code form the `getdb.ts`
[getdb1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXeNo.png)
[getdb2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBZfz.png)

how can i fix this with vite config ?. much appreciated for the help in advance